# LaTeX IfFontExistsTF returns True but 'font not found' error on compiling

Tags: fonts, fontspec, installing-fonts

I've downloaded and (definitely) installed a .ttf called Goudy Old Style Small Caps. When I run this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\IfFontExistsTF{Goudy Old Style Small Caps}{T}{F}
\end{document}
```

It prints T, but when I include this line between \begin{document} and the \IfFontExistsTF command:

```
\setmainfont{Goudy Old Style Small Caps}
```

it won't compile, saying 'font not found.'

What gives here? I've installed other .otf and .ttf fonts before no problem.

Comment: please say whether using luatex or xetex, and show the full log from the test file

Comment: LuaTeX. Here's the [log file.](https://pastebin.com/uFZJsQhZ)